# Need to retain values of checkings and savings variables through methods

Tags: java

I'm having a hard time keeping the values of the checkings and savings and being able to display the checkings and savings current balance.

```
package atmmethod;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author jfumar
 */
public class Atmmethod {

private static int option;

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //prompts user with options in simulation using methods

    do {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the new and improved atm program with methods!");
        displayMainMenu();
        double savings = 1000;
        double checkings = 500;
        System.out.println("savings balance is: " + savings);
        System.out.println("checking balance is:" + checkings);

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter option here: ");
        int option = input.nextInt();

        switch (option) {
            case 1:
                depositOption();
                break;
            case 2:
                withdrawOption();
                break;
            case 3:
                checkingBalance();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.print("Goodbye!");
                System.exit(0);

        }

    } while (option != 4);
    System.out.println("thank you for using the new atm");

}

public static void displayMainMenu() {
    System.out.println("Select options by numbers 1, 2, 3, or 4");
    System.out.println("1. deposit");
    System.out.println("2. withdraw");
    System.out.println("3. balance");
    System.out.println("4. exit");

}

public static void depositOption() {
    double currentSavings = 1000;
    double currentCheckings = 500;
    double amount;

    System.out.println("where would like to deposit your money?");
    System.out.println("1. Savings");
    System.out.println("2. Checkings");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter choice here: ");
    int choice = input.nextInt();

    if (choice == 1) {
        System.out.println("how much do you want to deposit in your savings?");
        amount = input.nextDouble();
        currentSavings += amount;
        System.out.println("your savings balance is now: " + currentSavings);
    } else {
        System.out.println("how much do you want to deposit in your checkings?");
        amount = input.nextDouble();
        currentCheckings += amount;
        System.out.println("your checkings balance is now: " + currentCheckings);

    }

}

public static void withdrawOption() {
    double currentSavings = 1000;
    double currentCheckings = 500;
    double amount;

    System.out.println("where would like to withdraw your money?");
    System.out.println("1. Savings");
    System.out.println("2. Checkings");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter choice here: ");
    int choice = input.nextInt();

    if (choice == 1) {
        System.out.println("how much do you want to withdraw from your savings?");
        amount = input.nextDouble();
        currentSavings -= amount;
        System.out.println("your savings balance is now: " + currentSavings);
    } else {
        System.out.println("how much do you want to withdraw from your checkings?");
        amount = input.nextDouble();
        currentCheckings -= amount;
        System.out.println("your checkings balance is now: " + currentCheckings);

    }

}

public static void checkingBalance() {
    System.out.println("CURRENT BALANCES");
    System.out.println("Savings balance is: ");
    System.out.println("Checkings balance is: ");
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

savings and checkings should be fields of your class, not local variables. Local variables are destroyed at the end of the method.

```
public class Atmmethod {

    private static double currentSavings = 500;
    private static double currentCheckings = 1000;

    //...

}
```

By the way all your methods and fields are static, which is not good, but that's another story

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a global variable for checkings and savings, unless I'm misunderstanding your problem. Whenever depositOption() and withdrawOption() are run it resets the balances to 1000 and 500. Just make currentSavings and currentCheckings global variables and then in the withdraw and deposit, add/subtract the amount the user inputs from the global variable.